# Number of variables doesn't match - prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

```
if (strlen($search) > 0)
{
    $query = "SELECT p.product_id,p.account_id,i.image_id,a.email,p.title,p.price,MATCH(p.title) AGAINST('?' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_images AS i
    ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.featured=1 AND i.deleted=0
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a
    ON p.account_id = a.account_id 
    WHERE MATCH(p.title) AGAINST('?' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY score DESC";
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT p.product_id,p.account_id,i.image_id,a.email,p.title,p.price
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_images AS i
    ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.featured=1 AND i.deleted=0
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a
    ON p.account_id = a.account_id";    
}


//Search the listings
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    if (strlen($search) > 0)
    {
        $statement->bind_param("ss", $search, $search);
    }
    $statement->execute();
}
```

This confuses me greatly but, if there is a $search provided, it spits out an error saying that  "number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement".

The other case where there is no $search works fine.

This is very confusing because there are two ?? and I bind two strings as parameters. Don't really understand what is happening.

Comment: Is not it supposed to be ```AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)```

Comment: I do that and it says number of variables doesn't match number of fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very confusing, but you can try:

```
if (strlen($search) > 0)
{
    $query = "SELECT p.product_id,p.account_id,i.image_id,a.email,p.title,p.price,MATCH(p.title) AGAINST('?' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_images AS i
    ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.featured=1 AND i.deleted=0
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a
    ON p.account_id = a.account_id 
    WHERE MATCH(p.title) AGAINST(:ss IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY score DESC";
}
else
{
    $query = "SELECT p.product_id,p.account_id,i.image_id,a.email,p.title,p.price
    FROM products AS p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_images AS i
    ON p.product_id = i.product_id AND i.featured=1 AND i.deleted=0
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a
    ON p.account_id = a.account_id";    
}


//Search the listings
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
    if (strlen($search) > 0)
    {
        $statement->bind_param(':ss', $search);
    }
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Comment: that doesn't throw any errors, no results either though. Weird error just don't get it.

Comment: If you run the first query in your db, you get an answer?

Comment: if no $search is provided the query works fine. The second query is fine if I put it into database and run it manually with values inserted where the ? marks are.

Comment: The code here is fine, i think the problem is in your query or in the way you are extracting the data. We can't see the all picture.

Comment: Thanks anyway Juan, I'll keep wrestling with this :)